# Javascript form success

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, message, send

I can't seem to get a success message to pop up with my form on my site. The message gets received but no indication is giving to the user via alert as it's meant to. Anyone have any ideas? Thank you :)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
$(function() { $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({ preventSubmit: true, submitError: function($form, event, errors) { // additional error messages or events }, submitSuccess: function($form, event) { event.preventDefault(); // prevent default
submit behaviour // get values from FORM var name = $("input#name").val(); var email = $("input#email").val(); var phone = $("input#phone").val(); var message = $("textarea#message").val(); var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message // Check
for white space in name for Success/Fail message if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) { firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' '); } $.ajax({ url: "././mail/contact_me.php", type: "POST", data: { name: name, phone: phone, email: email, message: message
}, cache: false, success: function() { // Success message $('#success').html("
<div class='alert alert-success'>"); $('#success > .alert-success').html("
  <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;") .append("
  </button>"); $('#success > .alert-success') .append("
  <strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>"); $('#success > .alert-success') .append('
</div>'); //clear all fields $('#contactForm').trigger("reset"); }, error: function() { // Fail message $('#success').html("
<div class='alert alert-danger'>"); $('#success > .alert-danger').html("
  <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;") .append("
  </button>"); $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
            });
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

Comment: It would really help if you formatted your code a little better. Right now it's really difficult to read.

Comment: This is legit just a copy paste from a template i downloaded from themeforest i think it was. I've made 0 modifications to it so far apart from my email addy which is in the PHP contact_me file.

Is it possible you need the bootstrapvalidation.js to figure it out? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What does `contact_me.php` send back as a response to the post? You might want to try putting an `alert()` inside the success callback to see if it's firing. Also, you probably won't get many replies here, since the code is really hard to read. It's like trying to read something written like this: jUstSoMe//diSreGaRDthIspARtsAMpletExt.

Comment: It sends me an email just fine. just the user gets no notification that their message has been sent to me.

Sorry for the sloppy text, i was having issues posting it properly in here for some reason, kept saying it wasn't formatted...

Comment: Do you have access to `contact_me.php`? How AJAX works is that the user's browser executes some JavaScript to send data to the server, and the user's browser will await a response (success or failure). The server then processes the data and sends back a response. Once the user's browser gets the response, it runs some more JS based on what the response is and how the callback functions were defined. You say that you're getting an email, so it's possible that `contact_me.php` is sending the email, but not sending back a response to the user. In that case, the AJAX callback never runs.

Comment: }
            $.ajax({
                url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    phone: phone,
                    email: email,
                    message: message
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function() {
                    // Success message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the functions you are using, but when I google for "Javascript message box", I receive a link to W3Schools "http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp", mentioning the three functions `alert`, `confirm` and `prompt`.

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

    $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
            // get values from FORM
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var message = $("textarea#message").val();
            var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
            if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    email: email,
                    message: message
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function() {
                    // Success message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append('</div>');

                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function() {
                    // Fail message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
            })
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation to your anwer